# load yaml values at application startup in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

I have some .yml files and want to load all of them at the application startup. I want them to be loaded in Some bean object. After this I should be able to access yml values anywhere in the application. is it possible to  do?

Below is yml.

```
Country:
-
    CountryName: Afghanistan
    CountryCode: AFG
    CurrencyName: Afghan afghani
    CurrencyCode: AFN
    Region: Asia
    SubRegion: Southern Asia
    LanguageName: Pashto
    LanguageCode: PUS
    PerCapitaRank: 170
-
    CountryName: Åland Islands
    CountryCode: ALA
    CurrencyName: Euro
    CurrencyCode: EUR
    Region: Europe
    SubRegion: Northern Europe
    LanguageName: Swedish
    LanguageCode: SWE
    PerCapitaRank:
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can load all properties into bean class by using `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "country")` [link1](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot) and [link2](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-yaml) annotation, since spring creates bean you can Autowire this bean at required place

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "country")
public class countryListConfig {

private List<countryList> list;

public List<countryList> getList() {
return list;
 }

 public void setList(List<countryList> list) {
 this.list = list;
 }

 public static class countryList {
 private String CountryName;
 private String CountryCode;
 // getters and setters

 }
```

And if you want to use these properties anywhere in application then you should declare them as static, since you can not Autowire static variables directly from yml file use setter mechanism

```
private static List<countryList> staticlist;


 public void setList(List<countryList> list) {
 staticlist = list;
 }
```

or you can also Autowire `countryListConfig` bean to a static reference in any utility class and use that bean all over the application

Comment: I tried above but it did not work. I was using that only but was not working with autowire.

Comment: just to inform my yml filename is country.yml. is it causing the issue?

Comment: use property resource annotation `@PropertySource(name = "props", value = "classpath:country.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = false)`  and also in yml change `country` to `country.list`